# Changing mat autocomplete values based on checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

Based on if the checkbox is checked or not, the values for the mat autocomplete need to change. When the checkbox is unchecked, the autocomplete should show the active Programs.  And when the checkbox is checked, the autocomplete should show the inactive Programs.

The steps of the problem I see is:

  1) Leave the checkbox unchecked
  2) start typing letters to see the active Programs
  3) backspace all the letters typed
  4) check the checkbox
  5) start typing letters and I still see the list of active programs whereas I should see the inactive Programs

It's as if I need to set the list of filteredOptions to an empty list after I check or uncheck the box.

Here is the code:

programs.component.html:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ProgramName" aria-label="ProgramName"
      matInput [formControl]="programNamesControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" size="14" >
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='getSelectedProgram($event.option.value)' >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" width:100px>
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="showInactivePrograms()" [(ngModel)]="programChecked" name="programChecked">
  <br/>
  <app-program-detail [programNameSelected]="programNameSelected" *ngIf="loadProgramDetails"></app-program-detail>
</form>
```

programs.component.ts

```
import { ProgramService } from './../program.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Program } from '../program';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-programs',
  templateUrl: './programs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./programs.component.css']
})
export class ProgramsComponent implements OnInit {
  programNamesControl = new FormControl();
  programNames: string[] = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  programNameSelected: string;
  loadProgramDetails: boolean;
  programs: Program[] = [];
  programChecked: boolean;

  constructor(private programService: ProgramService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.programService.getActiveProgramNames().subscribe(data => {
      this.programNames = data;
    });

    this.filteredOptions = this.programNamesControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  _filter(value: string): string[] {
    console.log('Inside filter..');
    return this.programNames.filter(programName =>
      programName.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );
  }

  getSelectedProgram(programNameVal) {
    this.loadProgramDetails = true;
    this.programNameSelected = programNameVal;
    console.log('Program Selected is: ' + this.programNameSelected);
  }

  showInactivePrograms() {
    if (this.programChecked) {
      this.programService.getInActiveProgramNames().subscribe(data => {
        this.programNames = data;
      });
    }
    else {
      this.programService.getActiveProgramNames().subscribe(data => {
        this.programNames = data;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

program.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Program } from './program';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProgramService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getPrograms(): Observable<Program[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Program[]>(environment.apiBaseURL + 'api/Program')
                   .pipe(
                     map(data => data)
                   );
  }

  getActiveProgramNames(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.getPrograms()
               .pipe(
                 map(data => data.filter(program => program.IsActive === 'Y'))
               )
               .pipe(
                 map(data => data.map(program => program.ProgramName.toString()))
               );
  }

  getInActiveProgramNames(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.getPrograms()
               .pipe(
                 map(data => data.filter(program => program.IsActive === 'N'))
               )
               .pipe(
                 map(data => data.map(program => program.ProgramName.toString()))
               );
  }


  getProgram(programName: string): Observable<Program> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Program>(environment.apiBaseURL + 'api/Program?programName=' + programName)
              .pipe(
                map(data => data)
              );
  }

}
```

Comment: Post the working version of your code in question on Stackblitz so that people can see the problem clearly.

Comment: If possible, please create a stackblitz demo for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the array, 'programNames' as soon as you shift the CheckBox state in the following method. As .subscribe() or other callback methods are asynchronous in nature. Those async methods would not apply an immediate effect when you switch the CheckBox until subscribe event is fired.

```
showInactivePrograms() {
    this.programNames = [];
    if (this.programChecked) {
        this.programService.getInActiveProgramNames().subscribe(data => {
        this.programNames = data;
    });
    }
    else {
        this.programService.getActiveProgramNames().subscribe(data => {
            this.programNames = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps to solve your problem!